# "letting" or "to let"?

Tags: grammar

There is a sentence in an English exercise book of mine:

"Place your knife and fork together on your plate, with the prongs of the fork facing upwards, __ others know that you have finished eating."

The blank part should be filled with the correct form of "let". I wrote "letting", but the solution says it's "to let".

Why isn't "letting" the/a correct?

Comment: Both are possible. _To let_ makes it clear that you do it _in order to_ let others know, _letting_ just indicates that it does let them know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both "letting" and "to let" are grammatically correct in that case, and in my opinion, unless there was additional context to the question, both of those should be considered correct answers.  They mean slightly different things, though:

> Place your knife and fork together on your plate, with the prongs of the fork facing upwards, **letting** others know that you have finished eating.

This says that you place your knife and fork that way, and in the process you will also let other people know you've finished.

> Place your knife and fork together on your plate, with the prongs of the fork facing upwards, **to let** others know that you have finished eating.

This says that you place your knife and fork that way, and the specific reason you are doing that is to make sure that people know you have finished.

So the first form just sort of says that one is a natural consequence of the other, whereas the second form says a lot more about what your actual intention is with the action you're taking.